# computer freezes and sound stutters

Tags: audio, windows-10, freeze, gaming

When I am playing any game on my PC, eventually it will freeze and the sound will stutter. Some small fraction of the time I can recover by mashing a bunch of keys like escape or tab. Usually, though, I have to do a hard reset. This has only been happening the last couple months since I installed FFXIV. Prior to that it was working fine with all the games I wanted to play (SWTOR, BF4, and others). Nothing gets logged in event viewer about the issue, the MSI control center doesn't do any logging, and SpeedFan basically just doesn't work on my machine. I looked at CPU-Z but it didn't seem like it would help me very much.  Windows Memtest utility didn't find anything wrong with my memory. Other recent changes: Windows 10 install.

```
MB: MSI 970A-G46
CPU: AMD FX-6300 (vishera)
MEM: 16GB
GPU: EVGA Geforce GTX 750 Ti (2GB)
OS: Windows 10
PSU:  Antec True Power 650
```

Prime95 Blend test:  after about 20 minutes CPU temp is 66-67C, which seems high.

FurMark:  20 Minutes burn-in test (8x antialiasing, 1080p, fullscreen) got up to 73C max, stayed around 70-72C, usually 98% TDP, 10FPS.  Did not do extreme burn-in

Occasionally it also sounds like a fan in my computer starts and stops without any particular reason.  There will be a clicking sound, then some whirring as it powers down.  Looking into the box, I can't really see any fans slowing down or stopping - looks like CPU, GPU and case fans all remain at constant speeds.  It's harder to see the fan in the PSU but the sound seems like it's coming from there.

Comment: As it's a typical symptom of *either* overheat or under-power, your first suspect would be the PSU.

Comment: do you think a 600w power supply would do the trick to replace an old 650?  I'm not sure I really needed that much power in the first place but if it's failing maybe it's not giving enough juice to the components

Comment: It would be worth a try; the 7xx use less power than the old 5xx did, with a 5 I'd say it needs 650, but a 7 might be fine

Comment: Went with a 650 from ThermalTake.  we'll see how it goes!

Comment: Wish you luck...

Comment: If you hear a fan clicking it means a mechanical problem.  You should replace any fan that you hear making a mechanical clicking sound.

Comment: The click only happens once per round of CLICK -> WHIIIIIINE.  It really sounds like a light switch being switched on or off.  So it's not clicking continuously.  And there are periods where it's not clicking or whining at all.  Curiously it does the most clicking and whining when the machine is doing the least amount of work.

Comment: @Tetsujin you should probably post an answer for this... *wink*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the solution I found was related to the kind of motherboard I was using.  There were some serious incompatibilities.  However, updating the power supply did a lot towards improving the stability of the system, so there was at least a contributing factor, there.

@Tetsujin provided me with the advice about the powersupply.